# Spring data redis implementation redis zrevrangebyscore operation

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a question because there is something that does not work well in the operation of spring data redis.

There was no problem with the inquiry when I used redis-cli, but when I use the API of spring data redis

- reverseRangeByScore
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ZSetOperations.html#reverseRangeByScore-K-double-double-

it failed to retrieve results, so I am asking if there is another way or if I made a mistake.

when redis-cli

```
$zrevrangebyscore redis_key +inf (1664142666 withscores

1) "189:Z0000539"
2) "1664432446"
3) "192:Z0000288"
4) "1664332797"
5) "178:0000cq4e"
6) "1664256182"
```

In Spring data redis

```kotlin
private val stringRedisTemplate: StringRedisTemplate
val now = Instant.now().epochSecond - (86400 * 7L);


val res = stringRedisTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRangeByScore(
            "redis_key",
            0.0,
            now.toDouble()
        )
res //<- empty
```

I'd appreciate it if you could give me your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `+inf` in redis-cli with `0.0` in spring-data-redis which does not seem a logical replacement.

Try `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` instead of `0.0`.